# What statistical test should I use?

Tags: statistical-test

I have 2 groups data which I'm trying to compare.

Neither are normally distributed.

My dependant variable is weight in pounds. 
My independent variable is interaction with a mirror measured in number of visits to the mirror in a 10 minute period.

My sample size is 18.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what statistical test to do.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the place to ask that, but you might want to look at what linear/mixed effects models can do for you

Comment: You should ask in [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I would probably say some mixed-effect model with an underlying distribution assumption.

Comment: @rg255 sorry, I didn't realise that! Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny I'll have a look! Thanks so much!

Comment: If your subjects are people then you'll have to include a gender interaction term!

Comment: @Edward my subjects are fish! And they're all male.

Comment: Are you sure that the dependent variable is weight and the independent variable is number of visits to a mirror? Sounds like it should be the other way around. And what are the two groups?